# How to trim trailing spaces from columns using a SQL statement invoked by a power shell script

Tags: powershell

I have a Power shell script that access an Oracle database and retrieves data to a flat file. The select statement should render 450K rows, 20 columns. But it renders only 40k rows, if in the SELECT statement i remove 6 columns i can render all the 450k rows. I think there are trailing spaces for these 6 columns that is causing some kind of issue. Can someone please tell me how to TRIM those columns?
I tried using TRIM in my SELECT statement but with no result. Please advice.

```
   $query =

 " SELECT 
       [ParcelNumber]
       ,[AltParcelNumber]
      ,[MapNumber]
      ,case OwnerName when 'NA' then 'Occupant' else OwnerName end ownername
      ,case OwnerName when 'NA' then '' else OwnerName2 end ownername2
      ,case OwnerName when 'NA' then '' else OwnerName3 end ownername3
      ,case OwnerName when 'NA' then '' else OwnerName4 end ownername4
      ,[OwnerAddress]
      ,[OwnerAddress2]
      ,[OwnerCity]
      ,[OwnerState]
      ,[OwnerZip]
      ,[OwnerForeignState]
      ,[OwnerForeignCountry]
      ,[Township]
      ,[LegalDescription]
      ,[Acreage]
      ,[PropertyClass]
      ,[PropertySubClass]
      ,[PropertySubClassDescription]
      ,[AddressNumber]
      ,[AddressNumberFraction]
      ,[AddressDirection]
      ,[AddressStreetName]
      ,[AddressStreetSuffix]
      ,[AddressStreetSuffix2]
      ,[AddressCity]
      ,[AddressZip]
      ,[FullAddress1]
      ,[FullAddress2]
      ,[Block]
      ,[Lot]
      ,[StateBlock]
      ,[StateTaxDistrictID]
      ,[TaxDistrict]
      ,[STR_Section]
      ,[STR_Township]
     ,[STR_Range]
      ,[AssessorDistrict]
      ,[SubdivisionID]
      ,[SubdivisionName]
      ,[LandNeighborhood]
      ,[Neighborhood]
      ,[NeighborhoodFactor]
      ,[TrendingFactor]
      ,[PlatBook]
      ,[PPFormType]
      ,[CondoType]
      ,[Sewer]
      ,[Water]
      ,[Gas]
      ,[Electricity]
      ,[Alley]
      ,[Sidewalk]
      ,[RoadType]
      ,[Topography]
      ,[AssessorYear]
      ,[AssessorYear_LandC1]
      ,[AssessorYear_LandC2]
      ,[AssessorYear_LandC3]
      ,[AssessorYear_ImpC1]
      ,[AssessorYear_ImpC2]
      ,[AssessorYear_ImpC3]
      ,[AssessorYear_LandTotal]
      ,[AssessorYear_ImpTotal]
      ,[AssessorYear_TotalAV]
      ,[CertifiedYear]
        ,rtrim(CertifiedYear_LandC1) as CertifiedYear_LandC1
    --- ,[CertifiedYear_LandC2]
      ----,[CertifiedYear_LandC3]
      
      ----,[CertifiedYear_ImpC1]
      ---,[CertifiedYear_ImpC2]
      ---,[CertifiedYear_ImpC3]
     ---,[CertifiedYear_LandTotal]
     --- ,[CertifiedYear_ImpTotal]
     --- ,[CertifiedYear_TotalAV]
      ,[Status]
   ,[AssessedDate]
      ,[CheckedBy]
      ,[CheckedDate]
      ,[UpdatedBy]
      ,[UpdateDate]
      ,[CamaParcelID]
      
      FROM viewname;"
Get-PVDAdhocQuery -Session $session -Query $query | export-csv    "\\Servername\Extract_Files\Parcel_extract_cloud_test.csv"
#Get-PVDAdhocQuery -Session $session -Query $query | Out-PVDQueryToFile -FileName "\\Servername\Extract_Files\Parcel_extract_cloud_test.csv" -Delimited -Delimiter "|"
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share what code you are using to retrieve the data?

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh thanks. I added the code to my original post. I tried Export as well.

Comment: "I tried using TRIM in my SELECT statement but with no result." - what does "no result" mean? Does it no longer return _any record_? Or still exactly the same as before (~40K rows returned)? Or slightly longer this time?

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen when i did a TRIM on one of the commented field it loaded 0KB , once i comment out all the 9 columns all the records are loaded. I think these 9 columns are the issue.

Comment: Any help please?